# Resolvable spaces

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

a space $X$ is called a resolvable space if it is expressible as a union of two disjoint dense subsets. I want to find a resolvable but not lindelof space? Is there any example such a space?

Comment: I find with a search:

www.renyi.hu/conferences/erdos100/slides/juhasz.pdf‎ which state that:
Every Lindelöf $T_3$ space $X$ with $Delta(X) > \omega $ is $\omega$-resolvable. as a theorem. So you should search for Lindelöf spaces which hasn't that property.

Comment: I think the The Moore Plane (The upper half plane, including the $x$-axis. Nhoods of points $(x,y)$, $y>0$ are the usual nhoods. Nhoods of $(x,0)$ are of the form $\{x\}\cup O$ where $O$ is an open disc in the upper half plane tangent to the $x$-axis at $x$) will work.

Comment: If you take a large enough disjoint union of $\mathbb{R}$'s, won't that work?

Comment: @GiulioBelletti what do you meant by take a large enough disjoint union?

Comment: @DavidMitra I don't think  that the Moore plane can be write as a union of two disjoint subsets.

Comment: The set of points with rational coordinates, and its complement.

Comment: oh yes, I see. Thanks.

Comment: @ghb I mean take a large cardinal $K$, and consider $\sqcup_{k\in K} \mathbb{R}_k$ with the disjoint union topology. This monster is not lindelof, but $\sqcup_{k\in K} \mathbb{Q}_k$ and its complement are dense.

Comment: @GiulioBelletti: thanks